# Is it bad practice to have arguments called in main() in Python

Tags: python, program-entry-point

Should the function name `main()` always be empty and have arguments called within the function itself or is it acceptable to have them as inputs to the function e.g `main(arg1, arg2, arg3)`?

I know it works but I'm wondering if it is poor programming practice. Apologies if this is a duplicate but I couldn't see the question specifically answered for Python.

Comment: This is a question primarily based on opinion. But no, it isn't bad practice. And in Python, anyway, there is no special status for a function named main.

Comment: Can we stop closing design questions as opinion-based, please -.- Just answer "Neither option is inherently better than the other" and boom, it's a useful question with a useful answer.

Comment: `main()` is just a naming convention, it does not matter what you do there, on the other hand, the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block should be minimal so that functionality isn't lost when importing the module

Comment: @Aran-Fey Totally agree, in Python best-practise questions are fine even if the answer is unclear, but apparently not everyone thinks this, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376232/should-i-ask-questions-about-idioms-or-are-they-too-opinion-based

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Yep, it's a sad state of affairs. Python style/design IMO is a **huge** part of learning the language, even if it's technically opinionated. Python code is **designed to be read**, not compiled and forever forgotten.

Comment: @jpp yes! I'm not sure why this is even controversial across other languages, there are idiomatic ways to do things in R, bash, C etc.

Answer (score 16):

In most other programming languages, you'd either have zero parameters or two parameters:

```
int main(char *argv[], int argc)
```

To denote the arguments passed through to the parameter. However, in Python these are accessed through the `sys` module:

```
import sys

def main():
    print(sys.argv, len(sys.argv))
```

But then you could extend this so that you pass through argv and argc into your python function, similar to other languages yes:

```
import sys

def main(argv, arc):
    print(argv, arc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv, len(sys.argv))
```

But let's forget about argv/argc for now - *why* would you want to pass something through to main. You create something outside of main and want to pass it through to main. And this can happen in two instances:

1. You're calling main multiple times from other functions.
2. You've created variables outside `main` that you want to pass through.

Point number 1 is definitely bad practice. `main` should be unique and called only once at the beginning of your program. If you have the need to call it multiple times, then the code inside `main` doesn't belong inside `main`. Split it up.

Point number 2 may seem like it makes sense, but then you do it in practise:

```
def main(a, b):
    print(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 4
    y = 5
    main(x, y)
```

But then aren't `x` and `y` global variables? And good practice would assume that these are at the top of your file (and multiple other properties - they're constant, etc), and that you wouldn't need to pass these through as arguments.

Comment: your 2nd snippet is where I'd put `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` instead of `x` a d `y`

Comment: i don't like your first snippet because `sys.argv` is empty when you import the module, i think the idea of `main()` is that it can be called either when the module is executed or when imported

Comment: @Chris_Rands Ah. I get what you're saying. Let me edit

Answer (score 9):

By following the pattern:

```
def main():
    ...stuff...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It allows your script to both to be run directly, and if packaged using setup tools, to have an executable script generated automatically when the package is installed by specifying main as an entry point.

See: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation

You would add to `setup.py` something like:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'my_script = my_module:main'
    ]
}
```

*2023 Edit: Also newer packaging tools like poetry follow the same pattern: https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject#scripts*

And then when you build a package, people can install it in their virtual environment, and immediately get a script called `my_script` on their path.

Automatic script creation like this requires a function that takes no *required* arguments.

It's a good idea to allow you script to be imported and expose it's functionality both for code reuse, and also for testing. I would recommend something line this pattern:

```
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    #
    # ... configure command line arguments ...
    #
    return parser.parse_args()

def do_stuff(args):
    #
    # ... main functionality goes in here ...
    #

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    do_stuff(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This allows you to run your script directly, have an automatically generated script that behaves the same way, and also import the script and call `do_stuff` to re-use or test the actual functionality.

This blog post was mentioned in the comments: https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829 which uses a default argument on main to allow dependency injection for testing, however, this is a very old blog post; the `getopt` library has been superseded twice since then. This pattern is superior and still allows dependency injection.

Comment: *Automatic script creation like this requires a function that takes no arguments*  ...not exactly.  You might well do `def main(argv=None):`

Comment: What would be the point in that? argv wouldn't be passed when invoked from the automatically generated script. But yes, this should say _a function that *requires* no arguments_

Comment: I've seen this pattern used so that the tests can pass in an argv list explicitly, rather than needing to monkeypatch the content of sys.argv.  Seems like a reasonable enough approach to me.

Comment: Guido himself recommends it on his blog:   https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829

Comment: Ok, dependency injection seems a reasonable thing to do, although I personally would probably just make main construct args and pass it to something else, and then test that function instead, so you don't have conditionals that change the behaviour under test.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely prefer to see `main` take arguments rather than accessing `sys.argv` directly.

This makes the reuse of the main function by other Python modules much easier.

```
import sys

def main(arg):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Now if I want to execute this module as a script from another module I can just write (in my other module).

```
from main_script import main

main("use this argument")
```

If `main` uses `sys.argv` this is tougher.

Comment: Other modules should not be using `main` directly.  They should use the same library code which `main` delegates to, after it is done parsing any arguments. Developers should endeavor to decouple the API from the CLI.